# Oracle: Fastest Way to Extract Filename Extension Using SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to get the extensions of filenames.  Extensions could be any length (not just 3) and they could also be non-existent, in which case I need `null` returned.  I know I could easily write a PL/SQL function that does this then just call that function in the query but I was hoping that I could somehow do it all inline.  And I don't really care how long the solution is, what I need is the **fastest** solution.  Speed matters because this will end up being ran against a very large table.  This is what I have so far...

```
/*
The same method is being used in all 5 examples.
It works for all of them except the first one.
The first one I need to return null
*/

SELECT substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1))
  FROM (select 'no_extension_should_return_null' filename from dual);
--returns: no_extension_should_return_null

SELECT substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1))
  FROM (select 'another.test.1' filename from dual);
--returns: 1

SELECT substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1))
  FROM (select 'another.test.doc' filename from dual);
--returns: doc

SELECT substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1))
  FROM (select 'another.test.docx' filename from dual);
--returns: docx

SELECT substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1))
  FROM (select 'another.test.stupidlong' filename from dual);
--returns: stupidlong
```

So is there a fast way to accomplish this inline or should I just write this in a PL/SQL function?

This is what I'm working with...

```
select * from v$version;
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

**UPDATE**
I'm moving this code into a function and will setup a test to call it a million times to see if the function slows it down, I'm thinking it won't make an impact since it's just string manipulation.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the answers so far.  I ended up making a PL/SQL function that does what I need...

```
create or replace function extrip(filename varchar2) return varchar2 as
begin
    if ( instr(filename,'.',-1) = 0 ) then
        return null;
    end if;

    return substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1));
end;
```

I then ran two tests against a table with 2 million rows.  When I viewed the explain plan for both they were 100% IDENTICAL.  How could that be?

```
select regexp_substr(filename, '\.[^\.]*$') ext from testTable;

select extrip(filename) ext from testTable;
```

**UPDATE**
I added a `order by ext` to both of those then reran the tests and there was a difference.  The regexp took 9sec and the function took 17sec.  I guess without the order by TOAD was just retrning the first X number of recs.  So @Brian McGinity was right.  I still need the regexp method to **NOT** return the dot "." though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will run fastest when done 100% sql, as you have.

The substr/instr are native compiled functions in oracle.

If you put this in a plsql function it will run slower due to context switching between sql and plsql:

This is slower due to context switching:

```
select extrip( filename ) from million_row_table
```

What you have is faster.

### Update:

try this:

```
select s,
       substr(s,   nullif( instr(s,'.', -1) +1, 1) )
from ( 
     select 'no_extension_should_return_null' s from dual union
     select 'another.test.1'                    from dual union
     select 'another.test.doc'                  from dual union
     select 'another.test.docx'                 from dual union
     select 'another.test.stupidlng'            from dual 
     )
```

Comment: Look at the **UPDATE** I added to my question.  I ran a test and the function seemed to have no effect on performance.  Am I not viewing the explain plan correctly (I use TOAD)?

Comment: I added a order by to the tests, appears you were right.  Function took 17sec and regexp way took 9sec.

Comment: Thank you. This worked in 1sec! Final version: `select substr(filename, nullif( instr(filename,'.', -1) +1, 1) ) ext from testTable order by ext;`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use regular expressions.

Try

```
select regexp_substr(filename, '\.[^\.]*$')
from
    (select 'no_extension_should_return_null' filename from dual);
```

I don't have an Oracle database to test this on but this should be pretty close.

Check the [Oracle docs on regexp_substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) and [Using regular expressions in Oracle database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm) for more info.

### Update

To drop the period from the file extension:

```
select substr(regexp_substr(filename, '\.[^\.]*$'), 2)
from
    (select 'abc.def' filename from dual);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the regexp method, but this answer fails on filenames with multiple periods like `another.test.docx`

Comment: Thanks! I voted up. I need fastest so once I have a handful of methods to try I'll run all against millions of recs and see which is fastest.

Comment: Actually I don't need to "." to be part of the result.  I just ran this example against a 2million row table.  Seems pretty dang fast.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NULLIF(substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1)) from (select 'no_extension_should_return_null' filename from dual) t1, SELECT filename from t1);
```

Sorry no oracle to test it, I'm sure you get the idea though.

Comment: +1 . . . Despite the bad formatting and the untested answer, this is probably the fastest method -- which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I couldn't get it to run as is, syntax error somewhere. I'll play with it in a little bit and see how it does.

Comment: NULLIF was the ticket.  I reformatted it correctly and it ran in 2secs with a order by just like the other tests against a 2million row table.  Final result: `SELECT NULLIF(substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)-instr(filename,'.',-1)),filename) ext from testTable order by ext;`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as per my understanding you can use DECODE function and query goes as follows:

```
SELECT substr(filename,instr(filename,'.',-1)+1,length(filename)- DECODE(INSTR(filename,'.',-1),0,LENGTH(filename),INSTR(filename,'.',-1))) from (select 'no_extension_should_return_null' filename from dual);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest would be to use

> regexp_substr(filename, '[^\.]*$')

It works on filenames with multiple periods and returns no period.

---

For filenames without extension next could be used

> select
>     case
>       when filename like '%.%' then regexp_substr(filename, '[^.]*$')
>     end EXT
>   from dual

Comment: The only problem with this one is if filename have no extension. So, for example, regexp_substr('test', '[^\.]*$') will return 'test'.